# How do I interpret a second-order multi-variate growth model?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, high-dimensional, growth-model, misspecification

I am running a multi-variate second order growth model.
I have two factors, which are conceptually related to each other measured on 7 different occasions.
Wanting to know how the two factors developed together overtime, I ran a multivariate
growth curve with the two factors.
When I first ran the model the model fit was not good.
To respecify the model, I added covariances among the first-order factors.
(So not among the second-order growth factors, these were already there from the first run.
I covarried time 1 factor A with time 1 factor B and the same for all time points)
The model fit improved and the fit was now acceptable.

My question is, what would be the interpretation of this respecification?

In my understanding, the covariances of the first-order factors are reflected in the
second-order growth factors as intercepts and slopes. And as they already have covariances among themselves, what exactly are the covariances among the first-order factors?

Thanks to anyone who would help me extend my understanding on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first-order factors themselves could not be correlated in a second-order growth model because they are endogenous variables (their covariances are accounted for by the second-order growth factors). What can be correlated are the *residuals* pertaining to the first-order factors. These latent residuals reflect time- or situation-specific variance components that are not explained by the second-order factors.

It can make sense substantively to correlate the first-order residuals across constructs at the same time point as time- or situation-specific influences/departures from the general growth trajectory may be shared across constructs. For example, both depression and anxiety states may be impacted in a similar way by a given event (e.g., daily hassle or uplift).

Comment: Thank you for your very swift response! As you mentioned I was aware of the weirdness of question because I knew that the covariances between the first-order factors should be already reflected in the second-order factors. I checked my code and textbooks and found out that my code was actually correlating the residuals of the first-order factors. Thank you so much for letting me confirm this!